# D3 Treemap parent and children

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, treemap

Trying to understand this example http://bl.ocks.org/hemulin/3247757 of the treemap which uses a zoom feature. Currently the treemap uses the children to display at level 0.I'm trying to modify it so it can display the parent at level 0 and when clicked on it will zoom in and display the children at level 1.

I've looked up Treemap example but don't quiet understand them. I'm not expecting someone to do this for me. Just a point in to the right direction would be great.

My code:

```
    var w = 1280 - 80,
    h = 800 - 180,
    x = d3.scale.linear().range([0, w]),
    y = d3.scale.linear().range([0, h]),
    color = d3.scale.category10(),
    root,
    node;

    var treemap = d3.layout.treemap()
        .round(false)
        .size([w, h])
        .sticky(true)
        .padding([10, 0, 0, 0])
        .value(function(d) { return d.size; });

    var svg = d3.select("#body").append("div")
        .attr("class", "chart")
        .style("width", w + "px")
        .style("height", h + "px")
      .append("svg:svg")
        .attr("width", w)
        .attr("height", h)
      .append("svg:g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(.5,.5)");


      node = root = pathJson;

      var nodes = treemap.nodes(root)
          .filter(function(d) { return !d.children; });

      var cell = svg.selectAll("g")
          .data(nodes)
          .enter().append("svg:g")
          .attr("class", "cell")
          .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; })
          .on("click", function(d) { return zoom(node == d.parent ? root : d.parent); });

      cell.append("svg:rect")
          .attr("width", function(d) { return d.dx - 1; })
          .attr("height", function(d) { return d.dy - 1; })
          .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.parent.name); });

      cell.append("svg:text")
          .attr("x", function(d) { return d.dx / 2; })
          .attr("y", function(d) { return d.dy / 2; })
          .attr("dy", ".35em")
          .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
          .text(function(d) { return d.name; })
          .style("opacity", function(d) { d.w = this.getComputedTextLength(); return d.dx > d.w ? 1 : 0; });

      d3.select(window).on("click", function() { zoom(root); });

      d3.select("select").on("change", function() {
        treemap.value(this.value == "size" ? size : count).nodes(root);
        zoom(node);
      });


    function size(d) {
      return d.size;
    }

    function count(d) {
      return 1;
    }

    function zoom(d) {
      //alert(d.name);
      var kx = w / d.dx, ky = h / d.dy;
      x.domain([d.x, d.x + d.dx]);
      y.domain([d.y, d.y + d.dy]);

      var t = svg.selectAll("g.cell").transition()
          .duration(d3.event.altKey ? 7500 : 750)
          .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x(d.x) + "," + y(d.y) + ")"; });

      t.select("rect")
          .attr("width", function(d) { return kx * d.dx - 1; })
          .attr("height", function(d) { return ky * d.dy - 1; })

      t.select("text")
          .attr("x", function(d) { return kx * d.dx / 2; })
          .attr("y", function(d) { return ky * d.dy / 2; })
          .style("opacity", function(d) { return kx * d.dx > d.w ? 1 : 0; });
          //.style("font-size", function(d) { return kx * d.dx > d.w ? "20px" : "12px";});

      node = d;
      d3.event.stopPropagation();
    }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/noobiecode/9ev9qjt3/1/

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed cell.text(function(d) { return d.name; }) to cell.text(function(d) { return d.parent.name; }). This now gets the name of the parent instead of the children.